# scala build with SBT cannot import java classes?

Tags: scala, sbt

I got some strange problems when using sbt to build a simple Scala class. 
The code is simply enough which I copied from internet to start a jetty server:

```
object JettyEmbedded {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(9080)
    val context= new org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext()

    context.setServer(server)
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setWar("src/main/webapp")
    server.setHandler(context);

    try {
      server.start()
      server.join()
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        e.printStackTrace()
        System.exit(1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to compile with SBT and scala 2.9.2, i got the following error:

```
[error] /src/main/scala/JettyEmbedded.scala:4: object eclipse is not a member of package org
[error] val server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(9080)
```

I can see in build.sbt, i have dependencies like:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.7.v20120910" % "container",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container;provided;test" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"))
```

If I just remove this offending file and run the Jetty server with container:start from sbt, it runs no problem!

Comment: to make it stranger, it compile and runs well in Eclipse/Scala-IDE

Comment: Are you sure you have jetty on your sbt classpath?

Comment: Do you have jetty as a dependency in your build file?

Comment: i edited the post. I think I do have jetty in my build.

Comment: Have you managed to solve it? I ve got the same issue (trying to achieve the same task - run embedded jetty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.7.v20120910" % "container",
```

to:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.7.v20120910" % "container;provided",
```

solved the problem.

sbt don't put "container" class into the compilation classpath, while in Eclipse it don't care.

Comment: I had to exit sbt and run it again. Thanks! Working now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the proper jetty dependencies in your `build.sbt` file.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "8.1.7.v20120910",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.7.v20120910"
)
```

Comment: Your dependencies are still wrong.  Try replacing the ones in your build with the ones in my answer.

Comment: What exactly wrong with them? Can you explain the difference? I have the same problem

Comment: He was trying to use the "jetty-server" dependency without referencing it in Maven.