# getting classes into the classpath with sbt

Tags: eclipse, scala, jetty, sbt, classpath

I am getting the following errors from sbt when I try to compile my project:

```
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:3: object eclipse is not a member of package org
[error] import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector
[error]            ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:4: object eclipse is not a member of package org
[error] import org.eclipse.jetty.server.{ Server }
[error]            ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:5: object eclipse is not a member of package org
[error] import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection
[error]            ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:6: object eclipse is not a member of package org
[error] import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
[error]            ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:7: object eclipse is not a member of package org
[error] import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.{ DefaultServlet, ServletContextHandler, ServletHolder }
[error]            ^
[warn] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:14: This catches all Throwables. If this is really intended, use `case _ : Throwable` to clear this warning.
[warn]        case _ => 8080
[warn]             ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:18: not found: type Server
[error]      val server: Server = new Server
[error]                  ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:18: not found: type Server
[error]      val server: Server = new Server
[error]                               ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:25: not found: type SelectChannelConnector
[error]      val connector = new SelectChannelConnector
[error]                          ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/JettyLauncher.scala:31: not found: type WebAppContext
[error]     val webApp = new WebAppContext
[error]                      ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/MongoDBServlet.scala:3: object Akka2Support is not a member of package org.scalatra.akka
[error] import org.scalatra.akka.Akka2Support
[error]        ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/MongoDBServlet.scala:8: not found: type Akka2Support
[error] class MongoDBServlet extends ScalatraServlet with Akka2Support {
[error]                                                   ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/MongoDBServlet.scala:13: not found: value ExecutionContext
[error]     ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
[error]     ^
[error] /opt/devel/src/sophia/src/main/scala/MongoDBServlet.scala:23: not found: value Future
[error]     Future {
[error]     ^
[warn] one warning found
[error] 13 errors found
```

The following is the contents of my `build.sbt` file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

mainClass := Some("JettyLauncher")

seq(webSettings :_*)

port in container.Configuration := 8080

seq(assemblySettings: _*)

libraryDependencies +=  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah-core" % "2.7.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % "2.2.0-RC3" cross CrossVersion.binary

libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-akka" % "2.2.0-RC3" 

libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % "2.2.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.mortbay.jetty" % "servlet-api" % "3.0.20100224" % "provided"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "9.0.0.M5" % "container"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-util" % "9.0.0.M5" % "container"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.0.0.M5" % "container"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/",
  "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Akka Repo" at "http://akka.io/repository/",
  "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"
)
```

The following is the contents of my `plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.9.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.7.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.5.0")
```

I generated an eclipse project because I could then look at the `.classpath` file. Sure enough, I found that some of these classes are not in the classpath...

How do I get these files into the classpath?

Thanks for all the help!

**EDIT:** I decided to dig through my JARS in `~/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.` I decided to first look for the `SelectChannelConnector` class (the first error I got from sbt). Inside the `org.eclipse.jetty` directory there is a `jetty-server` directory and so I went there. Now in the `jetty-server` directory there are a bunch of ivy xml files and two directories, one for jars and the other for srcs. I then went inside the jars directory. In the jars directory there are 4 jars:

```
jetty-server-8.0.0.M3.jar         jetty-server-9.0.0.M5.jar
jetty-server-8.1.8.v20121106.jar  jetty-server-9.1.0.v20131115.jar
```

The `8.*` versions are due to version changing in my `build.sbt.` With the comand `jar -tf [JAR-FILE]| grep nio' I found that the`SelectChannelConnector.class`file exists in the`8.*`jars and not the`9.*`jars. Note that my`build.sbt`specifies the`9.0.0.M5` jar.

My first thought was that sbt is solely looking at these `9.*` jars and that if I removed the `8.*` jars, and reloaded my project, that the right classes would get downloaded in the `9.*` jars. This was not the case.

I am not sure what else to try at this point. I could try to manually add these jars, but that sounds like a bad idea.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955230/scala-build-with-sbt-cannot-import-java-classes)

Basically you mark the `jetty-webapp` as `container` and `provided`

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.7.v20120910" % "container;provided"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, after changing to that "8.1.7..." version it did -- is that part of the container;provided keywords?

Answer (score 0):

You marked jetty as "provided". That means jetty is not available at runtime.

Comment: That is the `org.mortabl.jetty` if that matters. Regardless, I removed `provided` and did `clean`, `reload`, `compile` and it still did not work.